# Kendo Grid performance

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

We have a Kendo Grid control which displays data pulled from a database server.
There is no paging. All the data is pulled once and displayed with a scrollbar (depending on number of rows).

There are some user operations though involving a numeric textbox (input type number) column and a date control (input type date) column.
User could change the values in these controls which trigger onchange event handler functions written with javascript.
There are no server-hits in those javascript functions, and it's purely client-side code.

The problem we are facing is a slight UI blocking as soon as the change is triggered in either of the input controls.
When the javascript code is traced with console.log statements, it was found that significant times were spent in these operations:
`kendoGrid.dataSource.sort()`, `$("#dataGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.data(sortedDataObject)` and `$('#dataGrid').data('kendoGrid').refresh()`.

What I am looking for is a way for us to improve performance, which could include partial grid refresh (something similar to virtual scrolling with server paging) involving data visible in the display area of the grid, and partial grid refresh involving only some columns. I could not find a way to partially refresh the grid though after spending some time researching.

I am unable to paste any source code as I am not really sure how much code and what code could really represent the issue. That's why I attempted to present the problem more in words hoping I could get some solutions or approaches.

Comment: How many rows are displayed at once with no paging?  Also, I believe (but not 100%) that .sort(). data(), and .refresh() will all cause the grid to rebind/redraw as the grid and dataSource are MVVM bound to each other.  So, I think you are rebinding all your rows 3 times.

Comment: This may help: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/virtualization-local-data

Comment: can you please show the grid and  you made that the input controls ?

Answer (score 0):

As you've found, the grid auto-refreshes with most types of user interaction.  This can be expensive, is not always desirable, and can be stopped as follows:

```
var gridNeedsRefresh = false;

function onGridDataBinding(e) {
    if (!gridNeedsRefresh && isGridPopulated()) {
        e.preventDefault();  // cancel data binding to prevent refresh
    }
}
```

You'll need to implement the isGridPopulated method based on your particular grid details.  The idea there is that if the grid has no data or is still being loaded you don't want to interfere with that by calling preventDefault.  Once the grid has been bound, refreshing should be turned off:

```
function onGridDataBound() {
    gridNeedsRefresh = false;
}
```

Next is to determine all cases where the grid legitimately needs a refresh, and set the refresh flag.  For example, if your grid supports sorting or filtering, those require the refresh in order to function correctly, so you'll need to handle those events and set the flag:

```
function onGridSort(e) {
    gridNeedsRefresh = true;
}
```

Once the sorting completes, the onGridDataBound event will be called, causing the flag to be reset and the grid to become performant once again.